# returning required row/columns using python function(def)

Tags: python

When it comes to analyzing huge data, I thought it would be much efficient to make a function which can select required rows/columns for each analytics.

### The function I'd like to implement with dataset called "data" is,

```
def data_selection ( index_id = None , columns = None , rows = None):

# None is default of each variable, which means return all data
# index_id = [a,b,c] then only return index having [a,b,c]
# columns = ["d","e"] then only return columns "d" and "e"
# rows = "home" then only return columns["device"] == "home" rows 
                                 * columns["device"] doesn't change

data.apply(data_selection)
```

I tried those with using simple data.loc[:,:] function, but It doesn't work since the default is None.

Should I input if None return ":" or any better ideas on it?

Thank you in advance for sharing your ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` applies a function row-by-row (or, if specified, column by column). You would be better to write a function which takes the whole dataframe as an argument, like this :

```
def data_selection(df, index_id = None , columns = None , rows = None):
    if index_id is not None:
        df = df.loc[index_id]  # Select rows you want by index
    if rows is not None:
        df = df[df.device.apply(lambda x: x in rows)]  # Select rows you want by device column 
    if columns is not None:      
        df = df[[c for c in columns]] # Select columns you want
    return df

processed_df = data_selection(data, index_id, columns, rows)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked with applying index_id into not-None value, but when applying specific value in 'columns' and 'rows' variables, the error " AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' " came out. Could you please share comments with this error?